# Installing a custom ORION broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I currently have an scenario where I might need to install a custom Orion Broker to get sensor data from smartphones, since this data might be confidential, I'm afraid using the Fiware current Orion Broker is not an option, so I'm gonna need to install my own Orion Broker server. Having said that and knowing that there is Installation guide, I'd like to know if anyone has done this already and if so, what problems/challenges should one expect.

Thanks,
Alejandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different options are described in the ["Creating Instances" tab at FIWARE Catalogue page for Orion Context Broker](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker/creating-instances).

Among them, my recomendation is to deploy using the orion-psb-image-R*n* image, available at FIWARE Lab cloud.